# Bad font antialiasing for Qt6 applications

Tags: fonts, qt, fontconfig, qt5

Environment:

OS: Fedora 36
DE: XFCE
Font: Windows Tahoma
[Font config](https://itvision.altervista.org/files/fonts.conf)
`$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE`
Qt6-6.2.3-2.fc36

Problem: Qt6 applications seemingly do *not* use my fontconfig settings (which are used for everything else, including XFCE, GTK2/3/4 and Qt3/4/5 applications, and web browsers).

I've used `strace -e file` and `$HOME/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` is indeed being read but it's not seemingly used correctly.

I do not see any error messages in console from Qt6 applications.

I have a suspicion something in terms of fonts support in Qt6 has changed drastically but I haven't been able to find anything.

Here's how [Qt5 applications look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnonY.png) like.

Here's how [Qt6 applications look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xtNi.png) like.

I've filed a [bug repor](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-103488)t because I haven't been able to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by

```bash
export QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING=0
```

in e.g. `/etc/profile.d/fix_qt6_fonts.sh`

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html) for Qt6:

> `QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING` Set to `0` to disable high-dpi scaling; effectively reverting to Qt 5 default behavior. Note that this has no effect on platforms such as Wayland or macOS - it does not disable any native high-DPI support. This variable is intended for testing purposes only, and we do not recommend setting it on a permanent basis.